# C programming Loops

Tags: c

Iam working in this program that says:Calculate the average height of your classmates.
Enter the height in feet and inches.
Validate the feet to be in the range 3-8, and the inches in the range 0 to <12.
Display the number of students and the average height.
This is what I got so far, but, I don`t know if this is the correct form to approach it. I am stock right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char another;
    int feet;
    double inches, total = 0, average;

    printf( "Do you have a student? (y/n)" );
    scanf( "%\n%c", &another );

    while ( another == 'y' )
    {
        do
        {
            printf( "Enter inches: " );
            scanf( "%lf", &inches );
        }
        while ( inches < 0 || inches >= 12 );

        printf( "Do you have a student? (y/n)" );
        scanf( "%\n%c", &another );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use metric measurements?

Comment: @EdHeal ['cause.](http://i.imgur.com/E7UOjgy.png)

Comment: Where is your code to read the feet part of the height?

Comment: `"%\n%c"` --> `" %c"`

Comment: Have you tried running your code? What problem are you having exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` format for the "another" character should just be "%c". Otherwise, it looks correct to me.

Comment: `Have you tried running your code? What problem are you having exactly?` Should probably be a comment to the question, not an answer.